# Basic MCrypt string encryption with password implementation in C++

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, mcrypt

What is the basic setup on the subject?
Let say I have a QByteArray, and I need to encrypt it with simple password. And the application has to be portable to Linux, Windows and Mac.
Do I have to include mcrypt.h and mcrypt.c in the QT project?
And then decrypt it in another piece of code
Just a very simple setup

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at Qt Cryptographic Architecture (QCA)

http://delta.affinix.com/qca/

Should do what you need, is QT based, and is cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks, is it compatible with PHP MCrypt?